# cURL и современный Google (пароли приложений)

Tags: curl, gmail, пароль

Попалась вот такая [статья](https://habr.com/ru/articles/69110/) о том, как проверить количество писем на GMail с помощью cURL.

Попробовал повторить - не получилось. Как я понял, дело в том, что Google перекрыл с 2022 года доступ сторонним приложениям, и требует работу только через пароль приложения.

А как им правильно воспользоваться из cURL? Поиски в Интернете не помогли. Подскажите, или подскажите, где об этом прочесть.

Comment: Паролем пользоваться по идее так же, как и старым. Главное в том, что в сторонних приложениях теперь не светится пароль от аккаунта гугл.